# *.bundle.js files in source html page how to works in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular projects, I see `style.bundle.js`,`polifily.bundle.js`,... files in source page in my browser.

I will change these files name. For example `nava.bundle.js` replace `style.bundle.js`.

How is that possible?

Comment: do you want to replace the file names from the default to something else? Why you would do that?

Comment: compress file with address url